# How to find the sum of the string in java

Tags: java, string

In java how can we perform the below Arithmetic Operations?

```
String num = "42*65+223-55/23";
```

how to find the sum of the Above String?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with computer cores.  Please **read** the tag wiki's before you use them ... and don't use inappropriate ones.

Comment: Hi Abdul and welcome. I need a little more info to provide help. If you would like to evaluate the string as a math expression, then the link in the previous comment will help. Are you asking how to sum the integer values of the characters of the string ?